# I have created a GUI using tkinter, however, I only get the root window and it never loads the class?

Tags: python, tkinter

My code is below. The GUI opens the root window, however it does not create any of the widgets. I have been having issues with this for two days. All the info I get says this should work. I am also have issues converting the str from entry to float and continue to get errors. This is a project for my intermediate programing class.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application_Shapes(Frame):
    '''Creates and initializes the frame.'''
    def __inti__(self, master):
        super(Application_Shapes, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_labels()
        self.create_buttons()
        self.create_entry_values()

    def create_labels(self):
        '''Creates all the labels.'''
        '''Label for X '''
        self.xl = Label(self, text="X Value -") # assigns x1 var as a label.
        self.xl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E) # Puts the label on screen.

        '''Label for Y'''
        self.y1 = Label(self, text="Y Value")
        self.y1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky= E) # Puts the label on screen.

        '''Label for Z'''
        self.z1 = Label(self, text="Z Value")
        self.z1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E) # Puts the label on screen.

    def create_buttons(self):
        '''Creates all the buttons'''
        '''Button for circle'''
        self.button_circle = Button(self, text="Circle") # Creates a var as a button.
        self.button_circle.grid() # Puts the button on screen.

        '''Button for rectangle'''
        self.button_rectangle = Button(self, text="Rectangle ") # Creates a var as a button.
        self.button_rectangle.grid() # Puts the button on screen.

        '''Button for triangle'''
        self.button_triangle = Button(self, text="Triangle") # Creates a var as a button.
        self.button_triangle.grid() # Puts the button on screen.

        '''Button for trapezoid'''
        self.button_trapezoid = Button(self, text="trapezoid") # Creates a var as a button.
        self.button_trapezoid.grid() # Puts the button on screen.

    def create_entry_values(self):
        '''Creates the data entry lines'''
        '''Creates the x value entry field'''
        self.x_val = Entry(self) # Creates a var as a entry.
        self.x_val.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky= W) # Puts the entry on screen.
        x = self.x_val.get() # Gets the data entered and sets it as var x.
        x = float(x)

        '''Creates the y value entry field'''
        self.y_val = Entry(self) # Creates a var as a entry.
        self.y_val.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky= W) # Puts the entry on screen.
        y = self.y_val.get() # Gets the data entered and sets it as var y.
        y = float(y)

        '''Creates the z value entry field'''
        self.z_val = Entry(self) # Creates a var as a entry.
        self.z_val.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky= W) # Puts the entry on screen.
        z = self.z_val.get() # Gets the data entered and sets it as var z.
        z = float(z)


root = Tk() # Creates the root window.
root.title("Shapes Calculator") # Sets the title on the root window.
root.geometry("300x400") # Sets the root window size.
app = Application_Shapes(root) # Creates a var call app and asigns the class Application.
root.mainloop() # Runs the root window in loop.
```

I was expecting a GUI with three labels, three entries, and four buttons. When you enter a value in the entry field x and click circle the goal is to get the area using another set of class from a previous project. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The initialization method of a class is named `__init__`, *not* `__inti__`. The misspelled method never gets called, so the class doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: I have to admit, I haven't seen this exact typo before, but it's the same problem.

Comment: Thank you I have been beating my head against a wall trying to find my issue. Fixing the typo work.